# mount bed to aerated concrete wall

Tags: walls, bedroom, anchor

I want to mount a bed frame to 2 aircrete walls with a pillar on the unsupported corner.
I've heard that anchors can tear out parts of the wall if overtightened. My question is for a load greater than 200kg (440lb) what is the best method to use, I've heard one can use some sort of expanding Resin.

[image: A rendering of my idea]
Thanks

Benjamin

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. Typically you'd use an expanding *anchor*, such as a [split sleeve](https://www.concretefasteners.com/how-to-install-sleeve-anchors).

Comment: Do these not pull out parts of the wall if overtightened?

Comment: They will, as they would with regular concrete. I have no experience with aerated concreted and have declined to answer your question. Please don't interpret my comment as one. I'm just stating that foam isn't appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong. It was actually resin